# Redirect to particular view controller when getting local notification

Tags: ios, objective-c, uilocalnotification

I am trying to implement local notification and its working fine but my problem is when my application is in foreground and I got the push from the server it will alert me but when I tap on that alert and trying to redirect on my home view controller with the using this simple code in app-delegate file

```
- (void)didTapOnNotificationView:(CMNavBarNotificationView *)notificationView
{
    UIStoryboard *storyboard = [[self.window rootViewController] storyboard];
    HomeViewController *obj_home=[storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Home"];
    UINavigationController* navigationViewController_test=[[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:[storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Home"]];

    [navigationViewController_test pushViewController:obj_home animated:YES];
}
```

With this code it will show only black screen,can any one tell me where i making the mistake? and yes for the local notification alert I am using third party tool (`CMNavBarNotificationView`) and using its delegate method (`didTapOnNotificationView`)

Comment: Are you talking about local or push notifications?

Comment: talking about local notification but when i got message i just want to redirect on my homeview/firstview controller.

Comment: Okay, I've edited your question to remove all the references to push notifications.

Answer (score 0):

You need to link up the navigationcontroller with a viewcontroller currently in the navigation stack. Here in the below code I am using the rootviewcontroller to present/push the HomeviewController, you can replace it with any controller that you want.

```
 - (void)didTapOnNotificationView:(CMNavBarNotificationView *)notificationView
    {
        UIStoryboard *storyboard = [[self.window rootViewController] storyboard];
        HomeViewController *obj_home=[storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Home"];



      // either present the navigation controller as a modal 


        UINavigationController* navigationViewController_test=[[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:obj_home];

        [self.window.rootViewController presentViewController:navigationViewController_test animated:YES completion:^{}];

     // OR push the home view. Here my rootViewController is a navigation controller, so I am pushing the home view directly from it. You can push it from any of the controller that is in the current navigation controller stack.

        [(UINavigationController *)self.window.rootViewController pushViewController:obj_home animated:YES];

    }
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: ok..i solve it..can u help me which method called when application is in background and when i tap on notification on notification area?

Comment: when you tap on notification when app is in background state, the following method will be called

- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application 
didReceiveLocalNotification:(UILocalNotification *)notification {

}